# malloc()/free() in a loop

Tags: c, malloc, free

I have an assignment for a class where I have a text file, `bikes.txt`. The contents are attributes of bikes like so:

```
bike_id=16415
bike_station_id=455
bike_status=free

bike_id=6541
bike_station_id=1
bike_status=reserved

bike_id=5
bike_station_id=6451
bike_status=reserved
```

Right now I'm trying to read all `bike_id`'s, and I have a question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* getAttribute(const char* attr, const char* line);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("bikes.txt", "r");
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[256];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
        {
            if (strstr(line, "bike_id=") != NULL)
            {
                char* bikeIdText = getAttribute("bike_id", line);
                printf("\"%s\"", bikeIdText);
                //free(bikeIdText);
                //bikeIdText = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}

char* getAttribute(const char* attr, const char* line)
{
    int lineLength = strlen(line);
    int attrLength = strlen(attr);
    // +1 because of "="
    char* attrText = malloc(lineLength - attrLength + 1);
    // +2 because of "=" and NEWLINE
    memcpy(attrText, line + attrLength + 1, lineLength - (attrLength + 2));
    return attrText;
}
```

The above code works. The output is:

```
"16415""6541""5"
```

The problem is that - if I'm right - the `getAttribute()` function will allocate more and more memory which won't get freed.
However, if I uncomment the `free(bikeIdText);` and `bikeIdText = NULL;` lines in `main()`, the output shows that the same memory location is used, because the longer values won't get overwritten by shorter ones.
The output in this case:

```
"16415""65415""55415"
```

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: Try to set the last character to zero...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
  char* attrText = malloc(lineLength - attrLength + 1);
```

shall be

```
  char * attrText = malloc(lineLength - (attrLength + 1));
  attrText[lineLength - (attrLength + 1) - 1] = '\0' ;
```

or the equivalent

```
  char * attrText = malloc(lineLength - attrLength - 1);
  attrText[lineLength - attrLength - 2] = '\0' ;
```

This assumes `line` to end with **one** addtional character.

Comment: Thank you, this completes the answer given by the others. So to sum it up, the problem was simply not putting in the EOS -.-

Comment: @PéterLakos: "*... the problem was simply not putting in the EOS*" also the calculation for the amount of memory to allocate wasn't accurate, what however was not causing the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Last character of the string is not set to '\0' therefore, the "%s" prints more than it should (%s stops output at \0 byte).

Try to malloc one byte more `char* attrText = malloc(lineLength - attrLength + 2)` and set, `attrText[lineLength - attrLength + 1] = '\0'` before return.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the output is still not right, it's
"16415""65415""5541" now. Either this wasn't the issue or I have more errors.

Comment: @PéterLakos Your `malloc` and `memcpy` sizes don't seem to quite match... I suggest you put size to a variable, then use that variable for `malloc`, `memcpy` and setting the terminating 0-byte.